# Maya export to Three.js 'Infinity' values

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, maya

I have been trying to get a model exported from Maya to the .js format supported by three.js.

My problem is that when I use the exporter provided by the [three.js github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/maya) I get a file that contains values of 'Infinity' and '-Infinity' which gives me the expected error "uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token I"

-edit-
**To clarify on where the 'Infinity' values occur, they are all in my UVs**

I have also tried the [BlackTowerEntertainment](https://github.com/BlackTowerEntertainment/Tools/tree/master/MayaThreeExporter) version of the exporter and this produces no 'Infinity' values but rather an incomplete file that contains no material data.

I have also tried the [clara.io](https://clara.io/) route which produces a visible model, material data, but it seems they are unable to properly reference the textures in the materials.

Possibly a tutorial on how to actually get a model properly exported from Maya to three.js?

Comment: Hi from https://Clara.io!  We are working as we speak on improving the Clara.io exporter such that it references the proper textures.  It should be available soon after SIGGARPH (which is next week.)

Comment: can you upload the json and obj version of your mesh so we can take a look? Where are you getting these values?

Comment: @mindless_developer_man This is good news, I will keep an eye out for updates from clara.io, any chance you would be able to notify me when these changes might be in?

Comment: @pailhead I've edited question to clarify where the 'Infinity' values occur. My mesh is fairly complex, how should I go about uploading it?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably Maya/your model related.

Do you have the capability to break the mesh apart and inspect the mapping in a UV editor? 
If so, i'd try exporting piece by piece to pinpoint the problematic values.

If not, try to add some sort of mapping over the entire mesh (like planar) and check if you are still getting these odd values.

Comment: Yea, I'm thinking it's something that might be wrong with my mesh and/or settings in Maya. Unfortunately I'm not a 3D artist myself, I'm just a developer trying to get this to work. I've decided to try and write my own solution

Comment: you can replace all those values with 0 or 1 and it will work. It won't necessarily make sense, but you can tweak the texture to work with this. Just treat any vec2 with any one component that's invalid, as invalid and make both components 0. This will map that vertex to the corner of the texture.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know what what happens